# automation of Antivirus update in window machines on distributes systems

Tags: batch-file, automation, antivirus

I have a requirement of automation of Antivirus update in window machines on distributes systems , McAfee dat file updation on all windows7 machines . currently we are manually running dat file into all the Windows machines.

We are looking for something to run/schedule from the single machine on the network or the work-group of computers .
As per the research on the net, 
1. McAfee ePO
2. batch script to run on each machine ( which is exactly same as the running manually)

P.S: no Internet access in any of the computers.
any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hi SteveFest, honestly I was trying for the script with configuration file , which takes care of updating all the windows machines in the workgroup. during the course happened to discover the Epo. hence was curious to know about the pros and cons of it since its licensed product .

Comment: Uhm? What's inside the script? I wish I could know that.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 (batch file) would be free, obviously, and you could have it kick off via a scheduled task in Windows on each client, or you could put together a script that runs through a list of machines, stops the McShield service on each one, then copies the .dat over, and restarts the McShield service.

The way to go, though, is an ePO server. If you have enterprise licensing for McAfee products then ePO should be included. An ePO server would allow you to centrally manage all your AV clients and set policies appropriately.

Running a script to update servers is kludgy and messy. You'll have no feedback from your machines as to what got updates and what didn't.

Comment: Hi Johnathan , as far as i read on epo, it updates onto all the clients connected ( discovering through the network or workgroup) , do the user have an option to configure the clients ? I am afraid about the impact of using this in the critical system .I mean troubleshooting of the issues may be quite complicated as compared to  the script.                                                                                                        And Ia m planning to come up with one script in one severer(say centralized server) which executes the dat file on the clients in the workgroup.

Comment: I just read that Epo on a server should have internet access which allow to get the latest updated to push to local workstation on the network. Note we have no workstation that has internet access and we have VirusScan Enterprise running on all.

Comment: Policies can be configured via ePO to prevent users from modifying settings on their client.